# KeyError 'Label' While counting values in a single column

Tags: python, label, keyerror

I am unable to Find the number of values in "Label" column and getting error "KeyError: 'Label'". But for other columns same code working perfectly .
Here is my code `df_all['Label'].value_counts()

[image]

Comment: What did you enter as `In[1]` to `In[20]` in order to get `Out[20]`? Please show a [mre].

Comment: I enter "df_all.head()" to In[20]

Comment: That answers approximately 1/20 of what I asked. What came before `In[20]`?